# How to use jquery plugins (like Owl Carousel 2) with angular 4 in typescript class?

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to use jQuery plugins with angular 4 typescript class but unfortunately i am not successful to attain my objective.

I tried in many ways but angular 4 html component view didn't allow jQuery ready/other events so how can i use them?

I have currently created a component typescript class and tried to use jquery function in it but couldn't get success.

please see my code below :

```
 import { Component, Input, ElementRef, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'owl-carousel';

@Component({
  selector: 'owl-carousel',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class OwlCarouselComponent {
    @HostBinding('class') defaultClass = 'owl-carousel';
    @Input() options: Object;

  $owlElement: any;

  defaultOptions: any = {};

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // use default - empty
    // for (var key in this.options) {
    //   this.defaultOptions[key] = this.options[key];
    // }
    this.$owlElement = $(this.el.nativeElement).owlCarousel(this.defaultOptions);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.$owlElement.data('owlCarousel').destroy();
    this.$owlElement = null;
  }
}
```

Visual Studio compiler display the red error on this line.

this.$owlElement = $(this.el.nativeElement).owlCarousel(this.defaultOptions);

and error messages are :

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2339  Build:Property 'owlCarousel' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.   On.Store.UI L:\ESaleStore\On.Store.UI\src\On.Store.UI\wwwroot\app\shared\OwlCarousel.component.ts   24
Error   TS2339  Property 'owlCarousel' does not exist on type 'JQuery'. On.Store.UI (tsconfig project)  L:\ESaleStore\On.Store.UI\src\On.Store.UI\wwwroot\app\shared\OwlCarousel.component.ts   24  Active

this is my tsconfig.json

```
  {
  "compilerOptions": {    
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and this is my systemjs.config.js file

```
`/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
            jquery: 'npm:@angular/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            'owl-carousel': 'npm:@angular/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js' 
        },
        meta: {
            'owl-carousel': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

`

Kindly guide me . thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering whether your OwlCarousel is being correctly included.
There is a prebuilt module for OwlCarousel on npm ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-owl-carousel)), try that and see if it works for you.

Also, this post is about Angular 4, and so you should change your tag to `angular` instead of `angularjs`.

Comment: thanks adrian. i tried to install it with nmp and got this.why deprecated ?. .npm [On.Store.UI] install ng2-owl-carousel --save
npm WARN deprecated ng2-owl-carousel@0.1.15: WARNING: This project has been renamed to angular-owl-carousel. Install using npm install --save angular-owl-carousel instead.
angular-quickstart@1.0.0 L:\ESaleStore\On.Store.UI\src\On.Store.UI
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@4.0.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.0.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@4.0.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-

Comment: dynamic@4.0.1
+-- ng2-owl-carousel@0.1.15 
`-- protractor@4.0.14
  `-- @types/node@6.0.78 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'L:\ESaleStore\On.Store.UI\src\On.Store.UI\node_modules\Cartjs\package.json'
npm WARN @angular/upgrade@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/upgrade@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/upgrade@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.1.2 but none was installed.

Comment: npm WARN @angular/upgrade@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.1.2 but none was installed.
[On.Store.UI] install ng2-owl-carousel --save successfully completed

Comment: So it looks like there are several problems here, but mostly just follow npm's instructions. Use: npm install --save angular-owl-carousel to install. Try installing angular via npm.

Also, are you using angular-cli? The dependency issues look like your Angular install isn't managed by npm.

Comment: Adrian , please check my angular here.  I am new to angular 2+ so i just know the very basics.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310264/need-to-verify-angular4-from-angular2-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Adrian , what i understood that i have installation issues in Angular. it didn't properly installed/configured. I should use Angular like
npm install -g @angular/cli 
IS this link can help me . 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: Yes, if you aren't far in your project I would recommend using Angular CLI. However, it shouldn't be necessary. As long as you manually npm install it everything should be fine.

Comment: Adrian Smith. thank you. Can i talk to you for a while if possible ?

Comment: Yes, this comment chain is getting too long anyway. Shoot me an email at adrian@smithdev.io and I'll try to get back to you tonight with a more in depth guide. If it ends up working for you I'll post it here.

Comment: Email has been sent. I am getting these errors now when i installed the angular cli .


Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error TS2304 Cannot find name 'Set'. On.Store.UI (tsconfig project) L:\ESaleStore\On.Store.UI\src\On.Store.UI\node_modules\@angular\common\src\directives\ng_class.d.ts 48 Active